# How to output a table from the list

Tags: python, list

Now I have a list:

```
TIME: ['15:10', '16:40', '16:50', '18:20', '18:30', '20:00']
```

I need to output using a loop like this:

```
1. 15:10 - 16:40
2. 16:50 - 18:20
3. 18:30 - 20:00
```

Comment: Hello, What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Barmar OP's looking for *non-overlapping* chunks. Here's a duplicate for that: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice combination of `enumarate`, `zip` and slicing

```
values = ['15:10', '16:40', '16:50', '18:20', '18:30', '20:00']
for i, (start, end) in enumerate(zip(values[::2], values[1::2]), 1):
    print(f"{i}. {start} - {end}")

1. 15:10 - 16:40
2. 16:50 - 18:20
3. 18:30 - 20:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TIME= ['15:10', '16:40', '16:50', '18:20', '18:30', '20:00']
for i in range(len(TIME)-1,2):
    print(f'{i+1}. {TIME[i]} - {TIME[i+1]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate`, `zip`, and iterate the corresponding items and print the values.

```py
for i,v in enumerate(zip(TIME[::2], TIME[1::2]), 1):
    print(f'{i}. {" - ".join(v)}')
    
1. 15:10 - 16:40
2. 16:50 - 18:20
3. 18:30 - 20:00
```